# Does a "double yes" mean surprise or impatience?

Tags: irrealis-mood

In my post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643775/how-can-i-write-multi-line-code-in-the-terminal-use-python/44643976#44643976

I answer my own question, there is a comment here:

> Yes yes, that's right! plus one for that

The double yes means what here? Does it mean in favor of it?

Comment: "Plus one" in Stackexchange jargon means that the person has upvoted the question. Look closely at this question. On the left, you will notice an upward-facing triangle and a downward-facing triangle, with a number between them. If a reader upvotes the question by clicking on the upward-facing triangle, the number is increased by 1. This is called "upvoting", and this is what the commenter meant by _"plus one for that"._ Please read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is annoying, because "Yes, yes" can either mean added emphasis, or dismissal.

It's a context and tone thing, which is really difficult to discern in writing; it's much easier to figure out which is meant when you're speaking with someone aloud or in person.

Punctuation can help:

"Yes, yes! Let's do it!" -> "I am so excited about this I had to say yes twice!"

"Yes, yes, we know, you're very smart." -> "I am bored by this and want the conversation to move on."

It's very idiomatic and really depends on the tone. In your example it's probably the former meaning. The exclamation point and the "plus one" meaning an upvote probably mean they are enthusiastic.

Comment: Yes, yes, this is all true! (But without the commas, it could even be a typo.)